# How to skip tests in all phases of sbt builds (or maybe just in publish)

Tags: scala, sbt

A typical answer about how to skip tests in `sbt` would be:

```
 sbt "set test in assembly := {}"
```

However when I run for example

```
sbt publishLocal
```

Then that approach does not work.  Is there a ***global*** "disable" tests flag like

```
maven -Dmaven.skip.test=True
```

Or if not .. what would be the way to disable tests just for `publishLocal` ?

Comment: Are you using the `sbt-assembly` plugin? Have you tried to set the tests for the `publishLocal` task the same way?

Comment: sure I tried with `publishLocal` and the tests run anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable the test task in the global scope on the sbt shell like this:

```
set test in ThisBuild := println("tests disabled")
```

Usually `publishLocal` does not depend on the `test` task at all, unless you or a plugin are overriding the task. You can check in the sbt shell to see where it is defined and if there is a dependency on test:

```
inspect publishLocal
```

or for the full dependency tree

```
inspect tree publishLocal
```

It's possible that it is overriden to indirectly depend on `test` in another scope, in which case you can override it there.

Comment: We do have custom plugins - so it is likely that were the source of this. Great tips here thanks!

Comment: I have the following error trying to use this approach: `build.sbt:26: error: reference to test is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import Dependencies._
and import Keys._
test in ThisBuild := println("tests disabled")` .  Is there a way to disambiguate that actually this is the standard `sbt` `test` - not something in our custom classes?

Comment: it should work if you specify the full classpath of the `test` task: `set sbt. Keys.test := ...`